# Compiling litecoin on Macosx: llvm-g++ not found

Tags: litecoin, compiling

I'm trying to compile litecoin on macosx 10.8.5, I have Xcode installed along with command line tools and have built all recommended dependencies (boost db48 qt4-mac openssl miniupnpc).

When I run `sudo make -f makefile.osx USE_UPNP=-` I get the following error:

```
make[1]: llvm-g++: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [db/builder.o] Error 1
make: *** [leveldb/libleveldb.a] Error 2
```

Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated, all my google searches have been in vain.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who runs into this problem, the newest version of Xcode 5.0.2 and Oct 23 version of command line tools did not install the llvm-g++ file. I rolled back to Xcode 4.5 and installed the first mountain lion command line tool release and this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve these problems by installing dependencies with homebrew http://brew.sh/

it may also fix the problem to run Xcode-select --install in Terminal